# Can't save a file as JavaScript React

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I open a .js file, and change the language of the file to "JavaScript React" and then save the file, it works well. But when I close the file in VSC, automatically the program changes the file language to "JavaScript" again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `settings.json` add the folowing setting:

```
"files.associations": {
  "**/components/*.js": "javascriptreact"
}
```

Just modify the path where the React files are located.

**Edit**: You should do this in the Workspace settings if you want this to be restricted to a specific project.